# iOS 8 custom keyboard on device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I created an custom keyboard using the default template in Xcode 6 and when I run it in the simulator I see a keyboard with a "Next Keyboard" button.  However, when I try to run the app on my iOS 8 device, the keyboard will show up in settings but when I try to use it in the messages app the keyboard will not display.  How can I use the custom keyboard on a device rather than in the simulator?

Comment: After enabling your custom keyboard from the setting, you will see the `globe` button in system keyboard press+hold will display you list of enabled keyboard that you can switch into. Clicking `Next keyboard` will toggle.

Comment: I've tried that and sometimes I see my custom keyboard when long pressing the globe but when I select it the keyboard just disappears and my custom keyboard is not displayed.

Comment: Does your custom keyboard contains any button except `Next Keyboard` button, if not try adding the button at the centre specifying `attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by turning guided access off in accessibility settings.

Answer (score 1):

To test your keyboard on physical device, you have to change the value of the `RequestsOpenAccess` Boolean key in the `Info.plist` of your keyboard extension (not containing app)to `YES`.

now run application on physical device and grant access to your custom keyboard in keyboard section of general and now you can test it.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. Open access is for permissions such as dictionary, auto-capitalization, auto-period, etc, where keystrokes may be analyzed, or even sent to the developed. Open access is NOT required to test on a hardware device. Please down vote this answer!

Comment: @Codengine There is a bug on iOS 8.0.0, that sometimes prevents some  3rd party keyboards from opening on some devices, this solution was a temp solution for that case.